# Assigning DNS cname for APL AWS without using Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, elastic-load-balancer

I'm wondering if there is any other way to change DNS cname for ALB and not use Route53 for this aim?

Actually, We had two ELB on AWS and we have used DNS CNAME for them but now we have migrated to one ALB instead in order to have one load balancer.

For the DNS CNAME, we need to use Route53, we have an external DNS service provider, and we need to migrate our subdomains to Route53.(as it is faster than using the external DNS server).

I'm wondering if it is an efficient way to use Route53? and if there is any other way for assigning cname?

Comment: "change DNS cname ourselve" means can you elaborate?

Comment: @error2007s  do u know if there is any way except Route53?

Comment: If your domain is hosted on Route 53 and if you don't want to use Route 53 then you will have to move that domain to some other domain service

Comment: @ error2007s I'm not using Route53 at the moment, I wanted to use it because of DNS cname for ALB!

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking, @Sarah.  You can never change the *name* of an ALB, even if you use Route 53.  It is assigned by the system.  But it's an A record, not a CNAME, so "change" is not the correct question to ask.  You can *point a CNAME record to the system-assigned name of an ALB* using **any** DNS hosting provider... but in order to have your own hostname pointing at an ALB, you have to have a DNS hosting provider, somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for your comment. Actually we have two subdomains in a DNS hosting provider(UKE) I wanted to know if I can use Route53 and move these records to it instead of using that external DNS provider?

Comment: Okay, now we are getting closer to an understanding of the question, @Sarah.  Please explain what you hope to accomplish by using Route 53 for the subdomains but not for the entire domain (which appears to be what you are now asking).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've just edited my question, please check it, thank u.

Comment: `For the DNS CNAME, we need to use Route53 (as far as I found)`, this is not correct, unless there is something else involved that you did not mention. In fact, moving from two ELBs to one ALB shouldn't cause any major changes. Why don't you simply edit your current CNAME records (to point to ALB name)?

Comment: @DusanBajic We would like to use AWS services instead of any external service provider because it would take a lot of time if we want to use our external DNS provider, so this is why we want to use Route53. Also, in general, wouldn't it be better if we use aws services instead of external DNS provider?

Comment: "Better" is maybe not the right word, perhaps more convenient. Still, you should edit and make your question more specific. It is unclear what are you asking there at the moment :)

Comment: @DusanBajic I've just edited, hope it would be fins this time. I want to know if using Route53 is a good way for assigning CNAME (in terms of both price and performance)